# Graph problem related to connected and unconnected components in adjacent list

Tags: graph

Suppose we have an adjacency list representing a graph. We want to explore two scenarios: 1) If the graph consists of undirected edges and forms a single connected graph, and 2) If the graph contains undirected edges but consists of multiple unconnected graphs. Will the time complexity (TC) remain the same for both cases, as O(V+2E)?

What will be the TC?

Comment: Why did you tag this as question as `dsa`?  Removing `dsa` tag, as this has nothing to do with Digital Signature Algorithm.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "DSA" is a common abbreviation for "data structures & algorithms" which probably led them to make this mistake.

Comment: Then they should read the tag description carefully.  It clearly states to not use it for data structures.

Comment: And the graph tag clearly states it should not be used for graph theory questions.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity to explore both scenarios, a single connected graph and multiple unconnected graphs, is the same: `O(V + E)`:

- **Single connected graph**: A Depth-First Search (DFS) or Breadth-First
  Search (BFS) starting from any vertex would visit all vertices and
  edges exactly once. So, the time complexity is `O(V + E)`.
- **Multiple unconnected graphs**: In this scenario, you'd have to perform
  a DFS or BFS for each separate connected component. However, since
  each vertex and each edge is still part of ***exactly*** one connected
  component, you still visit all vertices and edges ***exactly*** once. Thus,
  the time complexity is again `O(V + E)`.

In both scenarios, the adjacency list representation allows us to visit all neighbors of each vertex efficiently, so the total time complexity remains `O(V + E)` regardless of whether the graph is entirely connected or consists of multiple separate components.

Note: You mentioned `O(V + 2E)` as the time complexity in your question. In fact, in an adjacency list representation, the sum of the lengths of all the adjacency lists is 2E for an undirected graph (because each edge contributes to two adjacency lists). However, we still refer to this complexity as `O(V + E)` because the `2` is a constant factor and is ignored in Big O notation.